# FullCalendar json feed crash

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm setting a Full Calendar using `eventSources` with a JSON feed.

I'm not sure wether this is a bug or me, but I can't setup my `eventSources` if I don't put an empty event source like this

```
eventSources: [{
    events: []
},
{
    url: '/myfeed',
}]
```

right before my JSON feed.

If I don't send the empty event, it seems that an internally var rangeStart is not initialized and then, I got a crash line 9050 saying that format can't be called on undefined.

Comment: do you want pass events as well as url too ..? try to use it differently put the `event:[]` outside of `eventSources:[]`

Comment: Yes, I need my event feed and only that.

As I worked, I added some more options to fullCalendar and now, the problem does not happen again.

If I got the time, I will post a fiddle to try reproducing the problem